# The domain of the site comes after the IP address in the URL after rewriting in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

The domain of the site comes after the IP address in the URL. The site is on fastpanel, the routers are not working because it is not working properly in the `.htaccess`

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

#location of your website

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Example: `http://5.3.2.1:7777/api.api`

I tried it like this as well:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

#location of your website

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/api.api(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: There's nothing in your `.htaccess` file(s) that would cause this. (Your 2nd `.htaccess` file won't actually do anything since the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ is incorrect.) Is `api.api` supposed to be the "domain"? Why you are requesting the site by IP address? At what point does the "domain come after the IP address"? Are you seeing a "redirect"? What URL are you requesting?